# how to fix TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'range'

Tags: python, error-handling

```
  number = 0
  for number in int(range(2, 101, 2)):
    number = sum(number)
    print(number)
```

how do I fix this code. It keeps coming back with

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'range'

Comment: Use `for number in range(2, 101, 2):`. Why do you need `int` at all?

Comment: `range()` always returns integers, you don't have to tell it this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to do with that?
You don't need to define 'number' and don't use int() there.

If you want to sum all numbers from 2 to 101 in steps of 2, use this:

```
num_sum = 0
for i in range(2, 101, 2):
   num_sum += i
   print(num_sum)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: I edited so that it is a answer